# Showing `\_tl` variables that contain `&` and `\hline` tokens

Tags: expl3

Automating table creation requires generating `\_tl` variables for the `format`, `header` and `content` portions of the `\tabular environment`, preferably each in their own `\cs_ macros`. With the help of the `TeX/SX` I got it all working, but one nuisance remains. In pumping content into the `\l_rn_tabular_tl` variable, in this MWE done manually, I will necessarily require the `&` character, and certainly would want to have the `\hline` available also. While the `\l_rn_tabular_tl` does the job when plugged into the `\tabular environment`, it will throw the `!Misplaced \noalign` ERROR for `\hline`, and the `!Misplaced alignment tab character &` ERROR for `&` characters if an attempt is made to display the variable. Using `\tl_show:N` produces no output, interestingly if adding a `\\` `!LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end` is thrown. Considering that pumping content into the variable may be a very convoluted process, not being able to inspect the variable leaves me without my principal bug-tracing tool. Any workarounds? Secondly, I am pleased to see the `$...$ mathematics mode` working, except that `subscripts` don't work, while `superscripts` do.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 24 November 2017
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:
%  %=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tabular_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\myTable{}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_tabular_tl {\hline Master~Col.& First~Col.&Second~Col.&Third~Col.\\hline\hline 1&$x^{23}$&$b_3&\\2&$\Omega$&ccc&\\3&xx&&\\4&&&df\\5&&&\\6&&&qwer5\\\hline}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %  \l_rn_tabular_tl    \\ERRORs
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \tl_show:N \l_rn_tabular_tl  %\\
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}
      \l_rn_tabular_tl
    \end{tabular}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\myTable
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine your code line by line.

```
1    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_tabular_tl {\hline Master~Col.& First~Col.&Second~Col.&Third~Col.\\hline\hline 1&$x^{23}$&$b_3&\\2&$\Omega$&ccc&\\3&xx&&\\4&&&df\\5&&&\\6&&&qwer5\\\hline}
2    \l_rn_tabular_tl
3    \\
4    \tl_show:N \l_rn_tabular_tl
5    \\
6    \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}
7      \l_rn_tabular_tl
8    \end{tabular}
```

Moving tokens to new lines is immaterial as we're under `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Line 1: you set a token list variable.

Line 2: the variable appears out of context; being it a TeX macro, after all, it gets expanded. Error ensues, because of misplaced `&` and `\hline` outside the context of a tabular.

Line 3: after the many errors, you get a forced line break, which may also produce an error.

Line 4: this is the right way to look at the variable's contents.

Line 5: the `\\` is basically out of place.

Summarizing, you should just use `\tl_show:N` after having populated the token list variable:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\myTable{}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_tabular_tl {\hline Master~Col.& First~Col.&Second~Col.&Third~Col.\\hline\hline 1&$x^{23}$&$b_3&\\2&$\Omega$&ccc&\\3&xx&&\\4&&&df\\5&&&\\6&&&qwer5\\\hline}
    %\tl_show:N \l_rn_tabular_tl  % uncomment for debugging
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}
      \tl_use:N \l_rn_tabular_tl
    \end{tabular}
  }
```

I usually add `\tl_use:N` when I want to deliver the contents of a token list variable in the input stream; it's optional, but using it seems more consistent.

Comment: What you say sounds plausible, however, regardless of whether `\tl_show:N \l_rn_tabular_tl` is uncommented or not, all I see is the table. Now, in my MWE of course I know what's in the variable, because I just put it in with the `\tl_set:Nn ...`. In my actual applications the variable is the result of a macro and, if plugging the variable into the `tabular environment` produces a table, fine, if not, I have no way of finding what's in it, making trouble-shooting a stab in the dark.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth The output of `\tl_show:N` can be seen on the console or in the log file. When debugging, using non interactive mode is not recommended.

Comment: ... now the penny has dropped, at last.